# listener argument must be a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firmata

[image]I'm using nodejs for my rfid that is hook up on my raspberry pi. What I'm trying to do is when I tap the id "6f124628" the led won't turn on unless another pin on the arduino is high. I'm using firmata protocol for arduino communication.

JS:

```js
function arduinoReady(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Firmware: ' + board.firmware.name +
    '-' + board.firmware.version.major +
    '.' + board.firmware.version.minor);

  var ledOn = true;
  board.pinMode(ledPin, board.MODES.OUTPUT);

  rc522(function(rfidSerialNumber) {

    console.log(rfidSerialNumber);
    if (rfidSerialNumber == "216264a9") {

      onjie.writeSync(1);

    }

    data = board.digitalRead(ledPin);
    if (rfidSerialNumber == "6f124628" && data == "board.HIGH") {

      LED1.writeSync(1);

      return;
    }
  });
```

But my code doesn't work and Typerror :

> "listener" argument must be a function

```
var http = require('http').createServer(handler);
app.listen(8080);
```

```js
function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/firmata.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading firmata.html');
    }
 
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: edited with picture of the full error

Comment: is this the file `main.js` ?

Comment: yes it is the main.js

Comment: Can you pase the `createServer` function ? @Onjieee I think the error is not there, is in the `main listener`

Comment: edited the post

Comment: What is `handler` for you? is like: `createServer({hostname: '127.0.0.1' ,port: '8080'} , function(r, res));` Did you tried to implement a simple callback there?

Comment: The led in the arduino is controlled by a button in a webpage using web sockets if that answers the question. I'm new to nodejs sorry :(

Comment: also paste the definition of you `handler`

Comment: pasted it. handler for my html file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the method `createServer`

You have to change the initialization of your method `handler`

Try changing the `handler` declaration to this:

```
var handler = function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/firmata.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading firmata.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}
```

And now, you're able to declare your server with:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(handler);
```

Comment: Still shows the same error. I think the problem lies on how I use the `data = board.digitalRead(ledPin)`  because when I remove it and the `data == "board.HIGH"` condition the problem disappears but I need the condition in my code.